# Best way to get 4 documents with one query?

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire

I'm using Firebase and angularfire (latest version). My data model is:

```
VENUES {
   [venue.id] {
      name: string
   }
}

SERVICES {
   [document.id] {
      venueid: string
      name: string
      price: number
   }
}

USERS {
   [user.id] {
      name: string;
      phone: number;
   }
}

RESERVATIONS {
   [document.id] {
      uid: <--- userID from users
      serviceid: <--- id of document from services collection
      name: string;
   }
}
```

So basically i need to show all of users reservations in my template:
{{reservations.service.name}} {{reservations.venue.name}} etc. The "main key" is userid. 
I created helper, to get single documents:

```
  doc$(path: string): Observable<any> {
    return this.afs
      .doc(path)
      .snapshotChanges()
      .pipe(
        map(doc => {
          return { id: doc.payload.id, ...doc.payload.data() };
        })
      );
  }
```

so its working when i need to get one document. To get all of reservations im using reference:

```
const $reservations = this.afs.collection('reservations', ref => ref.where('uid', '==', userID)).valueChanges();
```

and i get all of documents from resevations collection with provided uid.

I started working with nosql a few days ago. I do some research with switchmap, map, combinelatest(), but i dont know how to use it.

My questions is: How to combine all observables into one getting all documents based on userid?
I need to get document from reservations collection where userid, user data and service data (based on reservations.serviceid == services.document.id)

Thank you in advance!

btw.

i tried to use:

```
    const $reservations = this.afs.collection('reservations', ref => ref.where('uid', '==', userID)).valueChanges();
    const $services = this.afs.collection('services').valueChanges();

    return combineLatest($reservations, $services).pipe(
      map(([reservations, services]) => [...reservations, ...services])
    )
```

but it only allow me combine pipes with ref.where (i dont know serviceid until i get reservations)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Angularfire `leftJoin(afs, joinKey, joinCollection, limit=100)` function for this.

```
const reservations$ = this.afs.collection('reservations', ref => ref.where('uid', '==', userID)).valueChanges();
const reservationsServices$ = reservations$.pipe( 
  leftJoin(afs, 'serviceid', 'services') 
)
```

See a detailed description [here](https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/firestore-joins-similar-to-sql/).

Answer (score 0):

If someone looking for fast solution to join query i suggest to use:
https://github.com/AngularFirebase/133-firestore-joins-custom-rx-operators

in my case, i used leftJoinDocument. Here's code:

```
  leftJoinDocument(field, collection) {
    return source =>
      defer(() => {
        let collectionData;
        const cache = new Map();

        return source.pipe(
          switchMap(data => {
            cache.clear();

            collectionData = data as any[];

            const reads$ = [];
            let i = 0;
            for (const doc of collectionData) {
              if (!doc[field] || cache.get(doc[field])) {
                continue;
              }

              reads$.push(
                this.afs
                  .collection(collection)
                  .doc(doc[field])
                  .valueChanges()
              );
              cache.set(doc[field], i);
              i++;
            }

            return reads$.length ? combineLatest(reads$) : of([]);
          }),
          map(joins => {
            return collectionData.map((v, i) => {
              const joinIdx = cache.get(v[field]);
              return { ...v, [field]: joins[joinIdx] || null };
            });
          }),
          tap(final =>
            console.log(
              `Queried ${(final as any).length}, Joined ${cache.size} docs`
            )
          )
        );
      });
```

then in my page module:

```
  getClientReservations() {
    this.reservations = this.afs.collection('reservations', ref => ref.where('uid', '==', 'MwdM8bak78eE1omf6u04KtqlE2X2'))
      .valueChanges()
      .pipe(
        this.db.leftJoinDocument('uid', 'users'),
        this.db.leftJoinDocument('serviceid', 'services'),
        this.db.leftJoinDocument('venueid', 'venue')
      );
  }
```

Thank you tobias for providing me hint :)